# Why do dotted CSS borders sometimes show as squares instead of circles?

Tags: html, css, border

Consider the following code

HTML

```
<p class="dotted3">A dotted border with squares.</p>
<p class="dotted4">A dotted border with circles.</p>
```

CSS

```
p.dotted3 {border: 3px dotted #000;}
p.dotted4 {border: 4px dotted #000;}
```

Why does the border at 3px look like squares but circles at 4px?

[image: difference between 3 and 4px with dotted border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dRmb.jpg)

Comment: It may depend on browser, What's the browser that you are testing on?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour Google Chrome Version 92.0.4515.159 on a windows computer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like that's a common behavior in several browsers, probably for avoiding loss of border quality. Take a look at some examples.

**Chrome (version 92.0)**

[image]

**Edge (version 92.0)**

[image]

**Safari (version 12.1)**

Here, the dotted border is always showing as squares, even when it's wider (the image shows a comparison between 3px and 15px borders).

[image]

In **Firefox (version 92.0)**, the border doesn't get squared. However, you can notice a little loss of quality in its circles.

[image]